# How to change the line color of a bubble in highcharts dynamically

Tags: jquery, highcharts, salesforce

Can any one please tell me how to change the outer line color of a bubble in highchart bubble chart. Outer line color should be changed based on the value from controller. My sode is below

```
       series: [{
            name: 'Decision>24',
            color: '#6A5ACD',
            marker: {
            lineColor : ('{point.priority}' == 'Prime Prospect' ? '#ADD8E6' : ('{point.priority}' == 'Defensive Play' ? '#590000' : ('{point.priority}' == 'Future Play' ? '#FFA500' : ''))),
                   lineWidth:2
                },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '',
                pointFormat: '<b>{point.name}</b><br>{series.name}<br>Annual Value: {point.z:,.0f} <br> [{point.x:.1f}, {point.y:.1f}]<br/>{point.priority}'
            },
            data: [{!seriesDataSet1}]
        },{
            name: 'Decision12-24',
            color: '#6994c7',
            marker: {
                    lineColor : ('{point.priority}' == 'Prime Prospect' ? '#ADD8E6' : ('{point.priority}' == 'Defensive Play' ? '#590000' : ('{point.priority}' == 'Future Play' ? '#FFA500' : ''))),
                   lineWidth:2
                },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '',
                pointFormat: '<b>{point.name}</b><br>{series.name}<br>Annual Value: {point.z:,.0f} <br> [{point.x:.1f}, {point.y:.1f}]<br/>{point.priority}'
            },
            data: [{!seriesDataSet2}]}
```

linecolore should be changed based on the priority.

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle of the issue if possible

Comment: I am unable to add Js fiddle because it is a very big code and all the values are dynamic which are coming from various objects

Comment: `Series.update` and `Point.update` with `marker.lineColor`..?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `callback` and iterate on each point to set correct `lineColor` for marker and hover state.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7efs6vLm/

Comment: Thanks for the information. @ Sebastian Bochan, I have tried with your answer and got it.